# Selenium Firefox webdriver cannot see webelement given but Chrome can?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a test case that changes the time value in the dialog pop-up. To do so, I created a method named `setDateInput`.

```
public void setDateInput(Object date, WebElement input_date, String format) throws InterruptedException {
        if(date == null) {
            //leave the date as it is.
            return;
        } else if( (date instanceof Date) ) { //arg date is passed.
            String new_date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
            input_date.clear();
            input_date.sendKeys(new_date);
            return;
        } else if(date instanceof String) {
            input_date.clear();
            input_date.sendKeys((String)date);
            return;
        }
        
    }
```

When it is called by this code below, Chrome driver changed the `startInput` to 23:55 but firefox does neither `clear()` nor `sendKeys()`.

```
setDateInput("23:55", startInput, "HH:mm");
```

So, my question is, is there a different way to handle the text type input in Firefox webdriver?

Thank you in advance.

Update:
The start_time element in HTML code as following

```
<input type="text" id="StartTime" value="00:01" pattern="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" placeholder="HH:MM" class="form-control input-text time-field-hm" required="" inputmode="numeric">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer by myself. This solution is not exactly fixing the issue but this is more of workaround.

I just added a method `click()` before `clear()` method. Firefox webdriver then manages to focus on that element. And it clears and sends a `23:55` String to the input field. Weird way to resolve the issue.

Or simply `sendKeys("")` will do as well. Hope this helpful.